# Cookie return undefined in GWT

Tags: gwt, cookies

I have created cookie for user name. Its working fine.

But my problem is:
when i clear cookie and try Cookies.getCookie("uname"); then it will return undefined insted of null.

so how to deal with undefined value ?

I am trying that if uname is not set then goes to else part;

please help me.

Comment: You sure? [JavaDoc](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Cookies.html) says this it returns: _the cookie's value, or null if the cookie doesn't exist_.

Comment: yes @spider. I m sure. i am trying to check if cookie is null. but it never return null and return undefined.

Comment: Are you positive that you haven't _set_ the Cookie to "undefined" by trying to set it to `null` serverside? The GWT docs are very explicit and I'm not keen to assume a bug on their side in the first instance. Check your headers when you "clear the cookie".

Comment: Is it returning the string "undefined" or is throwing an exception that says the variable is "undefined". What browser is this, it sounds like it is an browser issue if it is returning the string "undefined" rather than empty. I agree with the others something on the server or client is setting the cookie to be "undefined". You might try clearing cookies, closing the browser and reopen to see if it has the same results. I have seen oddities when clearing cookies and the page is still open.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is like this. Failure by design, please see here
https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=2994

The recommended workaround works:

```
String val = Cookies.getCookie("uname");
if (val == null || "undefined".equals(val)) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

But normally it seems to work even without this workaround. In my case I got the 'undefined' on JavaScript level, but in Java code it was sufficient to check for null. The real problem which let crash the code was a few lines later and didn't have anything to do with the getCookie() method. So have a look if you really identified the line with the problem.